# Smarty to check select box value

Tags: smarty

I have two HTML Forms in a webpage. One having a select box. So i may want to check in second form if first form has selected some value and if it has, capture that value. I am using Smarty templates for these HTML form. Is there some workaround with this ? Thanks.

Comment: can you show your code

Comment: I think it's impossible with only smarty. Smarty is a template language which produce a html-code.

But if you want check _before_ display, you can load second form with parameters of first form so you can check the check status. If you want after display... you'll need javascript (I suggest jquery).

Comment: yes javascript solved. used getElementById to copy one forms variable to another forms variable.

Comment: Also 4 lines of code.. i wrote Dojo instead of jQuery